# show bootstrap modal but stop propagation of show.bs.modal event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want to open the modal, but I don't want the associated events `show.bs.modal` & `shown.bs.modal` to propagate. Is there a way to do this?

something like `$('#element').modal('show').stopPropagation()` or is there a way to wrap the call to modal so that no events can bleed out?

Answer (score 0):

Try folowing code

```
$(document).off ("show.bs.modal", "#element");
$('#element').modal('show');
```

Comment: this just turns off all the events. I want to be able to stop propagation sometimes without the side effect of crushing all the events that are attached.